# Is this character in Captain America: The Winter Soldier more relevant in the Marvel Universe?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

Apologies for a spoiler tag heavy question, but in *Captain America: The Winter Solider*:

> The leader of the SHIELD strike team, Brock Rumlow, is shown to be a HYDRA counter-agent.

At the end of the movie:

> He is fighting Falcon, but is taken out more directly by a falling helicarrier.

At the very end of the movie:

> We are implicitly shown a scene where he is being put on a stretcher, heavily injured but presumably alive.

Is there any reason why they deemed the last scene necessary?  Is this character relevant to the Marvel Universe, or does he become relevant at some point?

Answer (score 19):

**Yes**

The character in question is:

> [Crossbones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossbones_%28comics%29)

However:

> The events of The Winter Soldier set up a completely different backstory for Brumlow, even if it is still HYDRA related.  It's most likely they added the scene in case they want to use Crossbones as a villain down the road - but it's nearly impossible to tell in what capacity (although he does have an obvious connection to Captain America).

Comment: In particular, his costume at the end of the film has a resemblance to his costume in the comics.

Comment: Even if they don't show him as a villain later, having that scene probably made some fans happy because they acknowledged that that character exists, or something like that. It's called "fan service".

Comment: They'll acknowledge him as a villain later; he plays a very important part in Marvel lore. He's the man that kills a very important character later on. I won't spoil it.

Comment: @jamessheridan - Is it Dumbledore?

Comment: @Richard Spoilers!!!

Comment: @monty129 - I'm willing to bet that everyone reading this knows that at the end of Harry Potter 8, Gandalf kills Hermione

Answer (score 12):

> Is there any reason why they deemed the last scene necessary? Is this character relevant to the Marvel Universe, or does he become relevant at some point?

Yes, Rumlow becomes very relevant in *Captain America: Civil War*.

He returns heavily scarred as Crossbones.

[image: Crossbones]

> He has sworn vengeance on Captain America after their previous encounter. After being captured, Crossbones attempts to kill Cap using a suicide vest. Wanda saves Cap, but in the process, accidentally kills multiple people with the explosion.

This kicks off the main conflict of *Civil War*, which is whether or not the Avengers should have accountability and oversight.

Comment: Great addition to the existing info! +1 from me

Comment: Also, his gloves end up in — or rather, on — the hands of the Shocker in *Spider-Man: Homecoming*.